# Вывод изображения в письме товара prestashop

Tags: php, html, email, symfony, prestashop

нужна помощь знатока prestashop.
Возможно есть где то информация или кто то может помочь, в том как можно вывести в письме (в котором выводиться заказанный товар "название товара, цена, количество") Вывести изображение этого товара, возможно есть готовые участки кода под это дело, или хотя бы подскажите где копать.
Буду очень благодарен всем кто попробует помочь!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
  <title>Сообщение от магазина {shop_name}</title>
  
  
  <style> @media only screen and (max-width: 300px){ 
    body {
     width:218px !important;
     margin:auto !important;
    }
    thead, tbody{width: 100%}
    .table {width:195px !important;margin:auto !important;}
    .logo, .titleblock, .linkbelow, .box, .footer, .space_footer{width:auto !important;display: block !important;}  
    span.title{font-size:20px !important;line-height: 23px !important}
    span.subtitle{font-size: 14px !important;line-height: 18px !important;padding-top:10px !important;display:block !important;}  
    td.box p{font-size: 12px !important;font-weight: bold !important;}
    .table-recap table, .table-recap thead, .table-recap tbody, .table-recap th, .table-recap td, .table-recap tr { 
     display: block !important; 
    }
    .table-recap{width: 200px!important;}
    .table-recap tr td, .conf_body td{text-align:center !important;} 
    .address{display: block !important;margin-bottom: 10px !important;}
    .space_address{display: none !important;} 
   }
 @media only screen and (min-width: 301px) and (max-width: 500px) { 
    body {width:425px!important;margin:auto!important;}
    thead, tbody{width: 100%}
    .table {margin:auto!important;} 
    .logo, .titleblock, .linkbelow, .box, .footer, .space_footer{width:auto!important;display: block!important;} 
    .table-recap{width: 295px !important;}
    .table-recap tr td, .conf_body td{text-align:center !important;}
    .table-recap tr th{font-size: 10px !important}
    
   }
 @media only screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {width:478px!important;margin:auto!important;}
    thead, tbody{width: 100%}
    .table {margin:auto!important;} 
    .logo, .titleblock, .linkbelow, .box, .footer, .space_footer{width:auto!important;display: block!important;}   
   }
 @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
    body {width:340px!important;margin:auto!important;}
    thead, tbody{width: 100%}
    .table {margin:auto!important;} 
    .logo, .titleblock, .linkbelow, .box, .footer, .space_footer{width:auto!important;display: block!important;}
    
    .table-recap{width: 295px!important;}
    .table-recap tr td, .conf_body td{text-align:center!important;} 
    .address{display: block !important;margin-bottom: 10px !important;}
    .space_address{display: none !important;} 
   }
</style>

 </head>
 <body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;background-color:#fff;width:650px;font-family:Open-sans, sans-serif;color:#555454;font-size:13px;line-height:18px;margin:auto">
  <table class="table table-mail" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;-moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #afafaf;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #afafaf;-o-box-shadow:0 0 5px #afafaf;box-shadow:0 0 5px #afafaf;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#afafaf,Direction=134,Strength=5)">
   <tr>
    <td class="space" style="width:20px;padding:7px 0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" style="padding:7px 0">
     <table class="table" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width:100%">
      <tr>
       <td align="center" class="logo" style="border-bottom:4px solid #333333;padding:7px 0">
        <a title="{shop_name}" href="{shop_url}" style="color:#337ff1">
         <img src="{shop_logo}" alt="{shop_name}" />
        </a>
       </td>
      </tr>

<tr>
 <td align="center" class="titleblock" style="padding:7px 0">
  <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
   <span class="title" style="font-weight:500;font-size:28px;text-transform:uppercase;line-height:33px">Здравствуйте, {firstname} {lastname},</span><br/>
   <span class="subtitle" style="font-weight:500;font-size:16px;text-transform:uppercase;line-height:25px">{shop_name}</span>
  </font>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="space_footer" style="padding:0!important">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="box" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;background-color:#f8f8f8;padding:7px 0">
  <table class="table" style="width:100%">
   <tr>
    <td width="10" style="padding:7px 0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="padding:7px 0">
     <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
      <p data-html-only="1" style="border-bottom:1px solid #D6D4D4;margin:3px 0 7px;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:500;font-size:18px;padding-bottom:10px">
       Подробности заказа      </p>
      <span style="color:#777">
       <span style="color:#333"><strong>Заказ:</strong></span> {order_name} Оформлен {date}<br /><br />
       <span style="color:#333"><strong>Оплата:</strong></span> {payment}
      </span>
     </font>
    </td>
    <td width="10" style="padding:7px 0">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style="padding:7px 0">
  <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
   <table class="table table-recap" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse"><!-- Title -->
    <tr>
     <th bgcolor="#f8f8f8" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;background-color: #fbfbfb;color: #333;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;padding: 10px;">Номер заказа</th>
     <th bgcolor="#f8f8f8" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;background-color: #fbfbfb;color: #333;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;padding: 10px;">товар</th>
     <th bgcolor="#f8f8f8" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;background-color: #fbfbfb;color: #333;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;padding: 10px;" width="17%">Цена за единицу</th>
     <th bgcolor="#f8f8f8" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;background-color: #fbfbfb;color: #333;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;padding: 10px;">Количество</th>
     <th bgcolor="#f8f8f8" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;background-color: #fbfbfb;color: #333;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;padding: 10px;" width="17%">Итого</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="5" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;text-align:center;color:#777;padding:7px 0">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;{products} 
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="5" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;text-align:center;color:#777;padding:7px 0">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;{discounts}
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="conf_body">
     <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" colspan="4" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;color:#333;padding:7px 0">
      <table class="table" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
       <tr>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="color:#333;padding:0">
         <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
          <strong>товара(ов)</strong>
         </font>
        </td>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
     <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" align="right" colspan="4" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;color:#333;padding:7px 0">
      <table class="table" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
       <tr>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="color:#333;padding:0">
         <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
          {total_products}
         </font>
        </td>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="conf_body">
     <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" colspan="4" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;color:#333;padding:7px 0">
      <table class="table" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
       <tr>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="color:#333;padding:0">
         <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
          <strong>Скидки</strong>
         </font>
        </td>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
     <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" colspan="4" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;color:#333;padding:7px 0">
      <table class="table" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
       <tr>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="color:#333;padding:0">
         <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
          {total_discounts}
         </font>
        </td>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="conf_body">
     <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" colspan="4" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;color:#333;padding:7px 0">
      <table class="table" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
       <tr>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="color:#333;padding:0">
         <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
          <strong>Подарочная упаковка</strong>
         </font>
        </td>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
     <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" colspan="4" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;color:#333;padding:7px 0">
      <table class="table" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
       <tr>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="color:#333;padding:0">
         <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
          {total_wrapping}
         </font>
        </td>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="conf_body">
     <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" colspan="4" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;color:#333;padding:7px 0">
      <table class="table" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
       <tr>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="color:#333;padding:0">
         <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
          <strong>Доставка:</strong>
         </font>
        </td>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
     <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" colspan="4" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;color:#333;padding:7px 0">
      <table class="table" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
       <tr>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="color:#333;padding:0">
         <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
          {total_shipping}
         </font>
        </td>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="conf_body">
     <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" colspan="4" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;color:#333;padding:7px 0">
      <table class="table" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
       <tr>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="color:#333;padding:0">
         <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
          <strong>Всего оплачено налогов</strong>
         </font>
        </td>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
     <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" colspan="4" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;color:#333;padding:7px 0">
      <table class="table" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
       <tr>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="color:#333;padding:0">
         <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
          {total_tax_paid}
         </font>
        </td>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="conf_body">
     <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" colspan="4" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;color:#333;padding:7px 0">
      <table class="table" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
       <tr>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="color:#333;padding:0">
         <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
          <strong>Всего оплачено</strong>
         </font>
        </td>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
     <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" colspan="4" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;color:#333;padding:7px 0">
      <table class="table" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
       <tr>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="color:#333;padding:0">
         <font size="4" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
          {total_paid}
         </font>
        </td>
        <td width="10" style="color:#333;padding:0">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </font>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="box" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;background-color:#f8f8f8;padding:7px 0">
  <table class="table" style="width:100%">
   <tr>
    <td width="10" style="padding:7px 0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="padding:7px 0">
     <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
      <p data-html-only="1" style="border-bottom:1px solid #D6D4D4;margin:3px 0 7px;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:500;font-size:18px;padding-bottom:10px">
       Доставка:      </p>
      <span style="color:#777">
       <span style="color:#333"><strong>Перевозчик:</strong></span> {carrier}<br /><br />
       <span style="color:#333"><strong>Оплата:</strong></span> {payment}
      </span>
     </font>
    </td>
    <td width="10" style="padding:7px 0">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="space_footer" style="padding:0!important">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style="padding:7px 0">
  <table class="table" style="width:100%">
   <tr>
    <td class="box address" width="310" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;background-color:#f8f8f8;padding:7px 0">
     <table class="table" style="width:100%">
      <tr>
       <td width="10" style="padding:7px 0">&nbsp;</td>
       <td style="padding:7px 0">
        <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
         <p data-html-only="1" style="border-bottom:1px solid #D6D4D4;margin:3px 0 7px;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:500;font-size:18px;padding-bottom:10px">
                 </p>
         <span data-html-only="1" style="color:#777">
          {delivery_block_html}
         </span>
         
        </font>
       </td>
       <td width="10" style="padding:7px 0">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    <td width="20" class="space_address" style="padding:7px 0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="box address" width="310" style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;background-color:#f8f8f8;padding:7px 0">
     <table class="table" style="width:100%">
      <tr>
       <td width="10" style="padding:7px 0">&nbsp;</td>
       <td style="padding:7px 0">
        <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
         <p data-html-only="1" style="border-bottom:1px solid #D6D4D4;margin:3px 0 7px;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:500;font-size:18px;padding-bottom:10px">
                 </p>
         <span data-html-only="1" style="color:#777">
          {invoice_block_html}
         </span>
         
        </font>
       </td>
       <td width="10" style="padding:7px 0">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="space_footer" style="padding:0!important">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="linkbelow" style="padding:7px 0">
  <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
   <span><a href="{history_url}" style="color:#337ff1"></a>  <a href="{my_account_url}" style="color:#337ff1"></a>.   </span>
  </font>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="linkbelow" style="padding:7px 0">
  <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
   <span>
     <a href="{guest_tracking_url}?id_order={order_name}" style="color:#337ff1"></a>   </span>
  </font>
 </td>
</tr>

      <tr>
       <td class="space_footer" style="padding:0!important">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="footer" style="border-top:4px solid #333333;padding:7px 0">
        <span><a href="{shop_url}" style="color:#337ff1">{shop_name}</a></span>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    <td class="space" style="width:20px;padding:7px 0">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="'.$this->context->link->getImageLink($product['link_rewrite'], $product['id_image'], 'small_default').'" alt="" '.$product['name'].' width="100" height="100" />
```

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Спасибо за помощь, попробовал добавить этот участок к tpl, но оно в письме показывает лишь пустой квадрат..

Comment: А какая версия ps ?

Comment: PrestaShop  1.6.0.9

Comment: @YaroslavDomen https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/229948-how-to-put-product-images-in-customer-order-mail/?tab=comments#comment-2185948

Comment: Возможно сможете мне подсказать еще раз?
Где вписывается шаблон письма который доставляется? 
Так как почему то при статусе доставлено, у меня отправляет письмо о регистрации..
Спасибо.

Comment: @YaroslavDomen не понял вопроса если честно. 
Лучше обратитесь на форум - https://www.prestashop.com

Comment: Спасибо! Изложу понятнее, и в=напишу на форум.

Вопрос.
Есть папка mails в которой лежат шаблоны писем, например "account.html" шаблон письма об успешной регистрации.

Но меняя статус заказа на "доставлено" отправляется шаблон письма "о успешной регистрации (account.html).

Но в скрипте где то ведь указан путь у действия к тому или иному шаблону письма которое нужно отправить по исполнению этого скрипта.

Comment: Вот и спрашиваю, где могут быть расположены файлы которые задают  шаблоны письма которое нужно отправить.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь! 
Картинку можно добавить в шаблон письма путем редактирования файла PaymentModule.php, а именно заменой участка кода

```
$product_var_tpl_list = array();
                foreach ($order->product_list as $product)
                {
                    $price = Product::getPriceStatic((int)$product['id_product'], false, ($product['id_product_attribute'] ? (int)$product['id_product_attribute'] : null), 6, null, false, true, $product['cart_quantity'], false, (int)$order->id_customer, (int)$order->id_cart, (int)$order->{Configuration::get('PS_TAX_ADDRESS_TYPE')});
                    $price_wt = Product::getPriceStatic((int)$product['id_product'], true, ($product['id_product_attribute'] ? (int)$product['id_product_attribute'] : null), 2, null, false, true, $product['cart_quantity'], false, (int)$order->id_customer, (int)$order->id_cart, (int)$order->{Configuration::get('PS_TAX_ADDRESS_TYPE')});

                    $product_price = Product::getTaxCalculationMethod() == PS_TAX_EXC ? Tools::ps_round($price, 2) : $price_wt;

                    $product_var_tpl = array(
                        'reference'                 $product_var_tpl_list = array();
                foreach ($order->product_list as $product)
                {
                    $price = Product::getPriceStatic((int)$product['id_product'], false, ($product['id_product_attribute'] ? (int)$product['id_product_attribute'] : null), 6, null, false, true, $product['cart_quantity'], false, (int)$order->id_customer, (int)$order->id_cart, (int)$order->{Configuration::get('PS_TAX_ADDRESS_TYPE')});
                    $price_wt = Product::getPriceStatic((int)$product['id_product'], true, ($product['id_product_attribute'] ? (int)$product['id_product_attribute'] : null), 2, null, false, true, $product['cart_quantity'], false, (int)$order->id_customer, (int)$order->id_cart, (int)$order->{Configuration::get('PS_TAX_ADDRESS_TYPE')});

                    $product_price = Product::getTaxCalculationMethod() == PS_TAX_EXC ? Tools::ps_round($price, 2) : $price_wt;

                    $product_var_tpl = array(
                        'reference' => $product['reference'],
                        'name' => $product['name'].(isset($product['attributes']) ? ' - '.$product['attributes'] : ''),
                        'unit_price' => Tools::displayPrice($product_price, $this->context->currency, false),
                        'price' => Tools::displayPrice($product_price * $product['quantity'], $this->context->currency, false),
                        'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
                        'customization' => array()
                    ); => $product['reference'],
                        'name' => $product['name'].(isset($product['attributes']) ? ' - '.$product['attributes'] : ''),
                        'unit_price' => Tools::displayPrice($product_price, $this->context->currency, false),
                        'price' => Tools::displayPrice($product_price * $product['quantity'], $this->context->currency, false),
                        'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
                        'customization' => array()
                    );
```

Вот этим участком

```
$product_var_tpl_list = array();
                foreach ($order->product_list as $product) {
                    $price = Product::getPriceStatic((int)$product['id_product'], false, ($product['id_product_attribute'] ? (int)$product['id_product_attribute'] : null), 6, null, false, true, $product['cart_quantity'], false, (int)$order->id_customer, (int)$order->id_cart, (int)$order->{Configuration::get('PS_TAX_ADDRESS_TYPE')});
                    $price_wt = Product::getPriceStatic((int)$product['id_product'], true, ($product['id_product_attribute'] ? (int)$product['id_product_attribute'] : null), 2, null, false, true, $product['cart_quantity'], false, (int)$order->id_customer, (int)$order->id_cart, (int)$order->{Configuration::get('PS_TAX_ADDRESS_TYPE')});

                    $product_price = Product::get﻿TaxCalculationMethod() == PS_TAX_EXC ? Tools::ps_round($price, 2) : $price_wt;

                    $cover = Image::getCover((int)$product['id_product']); // array image
                    $id_shop = $this->context->shop;
                    $force_ssl = (Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED') && Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE'));
                    $language_prefix = $this->context->language->iso_code;

                    if (Configuration::get('PS_MULTISHOP_FEATURE_ACTIVE') && $id_shop !== null) {
                        $shop = new Shop($id_shop);
                    } else {
                        $shop = Context::getContext()->shop;
                    }

                    if ($relative_protocol) {
                        $base = '//'.($ssl && $this->ssl_enable ? $shop->domain_ssl : $shop->domain);
                    } else {
                        $base = (($ssl && $this->ssl_enable) ? 'https://'.$shop->domain_ssl : 'http://'.$shop->domain);
                    }

                    $base_url = $base.$shop->getBaseURI();
```

﻿﻿

```
                    $domain = Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_DOMAIN');
                    if (sizeof($cover['id_image']) > 0) {﻿
                        $folder = Image::getImgFolderStatic($cover['id_image']);  // folders inside /img/p/
                        $image = '<img src="'.$base_url.'img/p/'.$folder.$cover['id_image'].'-cart_default.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="213" class="imgm img-thumbnail" />';
                    } else {
                        $image = '<img src="'.$base_url.'img/p﻿/'.$language_prefix.'-default-cart_default.jpg" alt="" width="125" height="125" class="imgm img-thumbnail" />';
                    }

                    $product_var_tpl = array(
                        'reference' => $product['reference'],
                        'image' => $image,﻿
                        'name' => $product['name'].(isset($product['attributes']) ? ' - '.$product['attributes'] : ''),
                        'unit_price' => Tools::displayPrice($product_price, $this->context->currency, false),
                        'price' => Tools::displayPrice($product_price * $product['quantity'], $this->context->currency, false),
                        'quantity' => $product['quantity'],﻿
                        'customization' => array()
                    );﻿﻿
```

а так же удалением (или отключением "на ваше усмотрение" файла  class_index.php

После чего в шаблон письма (или в tpl шаблон к которому обращается письмо)
Например:

```
   <td width="20%" style="border-bottom:1px solid #D6D4D4;">
  <table class="table">
     <tr>
        <td>
           <font style="max-width: 125px;max-height: 125px;" size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
           {$product['image']}
           </font>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Вставить "`{$product['image']}`"